# Error Consumir .DLL hecha en C#, llamada desde VB 6.00

Tags: vb6

estoy consumiendo una DLL desde VB 6.00, esta fue hecha en C#, me envia este mensaje de error -2147024894 Automation Error.

Al final me genera la informacion que es la factura electronica, generando un XML y un PDF.

Saludos

Comment: Que dll es? como la llamas? cual es el codigo que esta provocando el error? que quiere decir que despues genera la factura electronica? asi como esta, tenemos que adivinar que pasa y la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, gnianchi, estoy generando el informe de facturacion de ecuador, la llamo exportarinforme, es sobre la generacion de factura electronica de este pais. Tengo un sistema en VB6 donde facturan y cobran ellos, ahora la facturacion electronico la hice en C#, para no hacerla de nuevo, estoy tratando de hacer este proceso.

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y explica bien claro en la pregunta que necesitas...